# Troubles with Xdebug 2.1.0, XAMPP 1.7.3, Win7 32bit

Tags: apache, xampp, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

Looking for some help with getting xdebug to behave with my setup. My goal is to be able to debug Joomla code.

First let me preface saying that about a year ago I was able to get a version xdebug to work with Eclipse PDT 2.1 with xampp under Vista 32bit. However, now I'm on a new machine, and I wanted to get everything working with the latest versions. I did so by following through [this walk-through](http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_your_workstation_for_Joomla!_development). Now, trying to do the same thing I can't get it to work.

First, as per the walk-through, I downloaded php_xdebug-2.0.0-5.2.2.dll. Quickly realized that I needed an xdebug for php 5.3. So, I found the xdebugs Tailored Installation Instructions and followed that. My php.ini section looks as thus:

```
[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="D:\xampp\tmp"
```

So this got the xdebug to actually show up in the phpinfo(). But, in Eclipse when I Debug As Php Webpage, it at first appears to connect, however if I step to the next line of code the debugger just sits there saying it is stepping, indefinitely. Sometimes apache will crash. I tried ports 9000, and 10000 with no avail.

What I did find out is, if I use the the php_xdebug.dll that comes with XAMPP 1.7.3, I actually can connect and step without any issues, EXCEPT, that version of xdebug apparently has a major bug in it that causes all my variables to be listed as 'Uninitialized'. So it is basically useless, however, it does give some hope that I have some of this stuff set up correctly.

So, my current setup thus: Win7 32bit, XAMPP 1.7.3 (PHP 5.3.1, Apache 2.2.14), Eclipse PDT 2.2

I have very limited experience with basically all the tools here so I'm kinda at a loss of what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I searched some of the other posts here with similar issue but most of them appear to be for older versions of these components.

Comment: Well, I went back to xampp 1.7.0 (which uses PHP 5.2.8). Got the right xdebug for that, and everything works fine now. Still would like to know what's up with 1.7.3 though.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062318/xdebug-not-working-with-xampp/9092019#9092019 for an answer if you havent solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

your report is somewhat confusing. As far as I understand you, your setup works as soon as you replace the XDebug-dll. Then your (primary) problem cannot be related to your settings, as far as you also adjusted zend_extension, of course.

Though xdebug.remote_port=10000 seems odd. Std is 9000. If you use 9000, the you have to tell Eclipse in Window/Preferences/PHP/Debug/Debuggers to also listen to that port for XDebug.

Best

Raffael

Comment: My setup works as soon as I use the older version of PHP with the correct and older version of xdebug. I can't get anything to work with the newer version of PHP.
Like I said, at this point I have a working solution, but it would be nice to know why I can't get the newer versions of PHP and Xdebug to work. That type of info would help me know when I can get newer versions of the tools -- when issues have been understood and fixed.